# Why ahref isn't linking to some webpages

Tags: html

I'm creating a website using html and I have 4 webpages and I'm using ahref to link to those pages but only 2 pages work when I click them. The other two do nothing. This is the code I'm using:

```
<TABLE>

<TR> <TD>
<A HREF="HOME.HTML" TARGET="CENTER"> <IMG SRC="HOME.JPG" WIDTH="300" HEIGHT="200">  </A>

</TD> </TR>

<TR> <TD>
<A HREF="ABOUT.HTML" TARGET="CENTER"> <IMG SRC="ABOUT.JPG" WIDTH="300" HEIGHT="200">  </A>

</TD> </TR>

<TR> <TD>
<A HREF="GALLERY.HTML" TARGET="CENTER"> <IMG SRC="GALLERY.JPG" WIDTH="300" HEIGHT="200">  </A>

</TD> </TR>

<TR> <TD>
<A HREF="CONTACT.HTML" TARGET="CENTER"> <IMG SRC="CONTACT.JPG" WIDTH="300" HEIGHT="200">  </A>

</TD> </TR>
</TABLE>
```

I've save the html files all in the same place under the names listed above. 
Also when I change to the code for my About page to this:

```
<A HREF="HOME.HTML" TARGET="CENTER"> <IMG SRC="ABOUT.JPG" WIDTH="300" HEIGHT="200">  </A>
```

It works. Something is work with my About Page, but I can't figure out what. I even copied the exact code the homepage, and it still didn't work.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: you really should do your HTML in lowercase UPPER CASE MAKES FOR BAD PRACTICE + SHOUTING CODE IS NEVER FRIENDLY TO READ

Comment: also, you're using uppercase file names for your href values - but UNIX based systems are case-sensitive, `FILE.HTML` and `file.html` are two different files - what OS are you using to serve the content?

Comment: Also tables should not be used for layout - only tabular data